# Error phpMyAdmin - #1156 - Got packets out of order.

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, servidor, wamp

Acabo de instalar WampServer y los servicios se iniciar de forma correcta.
Al intentar ingresar a `localhost:88/phpmyadmin/` , me aparece el siguiente problema.

[image: Error WampServer - PhpMyAdmin]

**Notas:**

1. Yo cambie al puerto 80 a 88 para no tener conflictos con otros programas que ocupan el puerto 80.
2. El WampServer inicia los servicios correctamente. Adjunto captura.

[image: Conexión exitosa a localhost por el puerto 88]

Espero me puedan ayudar, quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: Te recomiendo que dejes el PHPMyAdmin y uses el SQLYog, en mi opinion personal es muy bueno, con el único inconveniente que no hay versión en español, pero si puedes lidiar con eso. Te lo recomiendo.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema, pero lo malo es que aunque desistale el MySQL Worbench no me deja aun asi

Answer (score 1):

Solucioné el problema desinstalando MySQLWorkbench y OracleSQL para posteriormente reinstalar WampServer y ahora puedo ingresar sin ningún problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví sin desinstalar WORKBENCH, simplemente deteniendo el servicio de mysql.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, agrega más información a tu pregunta, revisar [answer]

Answer (score 0):

La forma de que te deje usar phpMyAdmin es:
DESACTIVANDO EL SERVIVICIO DE MYSQL.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.